# IBM db2 Patch History

Tags: db2

Is there a query for extracting the list of patches applied to the IBM db2 database? I need to extract the complete list of patches that were applied to the database including the latest patch applied.

Comment: What platform? What do you consider "patch"? DB2 LUW has fixpacks

Comment: @data_henrik : Patches like they have on any database server like SQL or Oracle. I understand that fixpack is the equivalent of a patch in DB2. Can we get a list of all the fixes applied?

Comment: You can get the code level via SQL. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0060901.html?pos=2 There is no single patch, but there could be special code levels (special builds).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps db2 "select * from sysibm.sysversions" is an option